# Create-react-app doesn't allow import component.js from node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app

I received error when try to `import { PrimaryButton } from 'my-npm-modules/src/button'` ( which is a flowtype src jsx file with extension .js)?

Is it because the create-react-app have config to NOT do flowtype processing for files in node_modules?

```
Module parse failed: /Users/me/live-demo/node_modules/my-npm-modules/src/button.js Unexpected token (2:35)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| //@flow
| import React from 'react';
| export function PrimaryButton(props: {
|     text: string;
|     onClick: ()=>void
```

When I put the button.js inside the live-demo project, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it did exclude the node_modules folder for performance reason.

So I endup compile the flow-typed jsx --> normal js files, and provided js.flow at the same output folder for sake of consumer flowtype support.